# Sorting a linked list in C++?

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have been struggling for hours with this problem. My goal is to sort a linked list in ascending order using only pointers (I cannot place the linked list elements into a vecter or array and then sort that).

I am free to use as many pointers as I want. The only methods I can call on the pointers are `head->next` (next node) and `head->info` (strings stored in the node, used to make comparisons).

**And I don't want to change the information about any node, because they are connected to other valuable data, I need to change the order of the nodes, not the information stored in them.**

I have been using my whiteboard excessively, and have tried just about everything I can think of, and this is the best solution I have, which does not work:

```
tmpPtr1=MyNameList.head; //A pointer to the head of the node 
tmpPtr2=MyNameList.head->next; //A pointer to the node that comes after the head
while(tmpPtr1!=0) //Runs until pointer reaches to the end of the linked list
{
    while(tmpPtr2!=0) //Runs until pointer reaches to the end of the linked list
    {
        if((tmpPtr1->info) > (tmpPtr2->info))
        {
             LinkedMLLNode<string> *tmpPtr4; //Creating a temporary node to swap nodes.
             tmpPtr4=tmpPtr2->next;
             tmpPtr2->next=tmpPtr1;
             tmpPtr1->next=tmpPtr4;
             tmpPtr2=tmpPtr4;
        }
        else
        {
            tmpPtr1=tmpPtr1->next;
            tmpPtr2=tmpPtr2->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Recommendation: Write a `swap` function that exchanges two nodes (note that sometimes it's a lot cheaper to swap the contents of the nodes than to swap the nodes themselves) and use the swap function in a common sorting algorithm so that you don't have to completely roll-your own.

Comment: Yes, but no. I cannot change the contents of the nodes. They are connected to other relevant data. I need to change the order of the nodes.

Comment: can you use a double link list? or want a forward list?

Comment: I cannot use a double link list only forward.